# How to increase database insert performance with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, insert, sql-server-ce, database-performance

I have my first project with Entity Framework and SQL Server Compact.

The database has about 15 tables which all have foreign keys to other tables.
I have to read thousands of XML files and import their data to the database. The database structure mirrors the XML file structure. There is a table hierarchy with up to 5 levels. So for each record in the "top" table I have to insert one or more in the underlying tables.

I am using Entity Framework for inserting and it works fine, but the performance is very very poor :(. 
I think the main problem is that for most records the ID has to be read back to be used for records in underlying tables.

The other thing is that - if I know right - that Entity Framework inserts each record with a separate command.

Is there a way to increase the performance dramatically?

Thank you

Comment: If performance is an issue, the easiest workaround is manual SQL queries.

Comment: Is this a one time (initialization) action? Then you can disable all constraints in sql server. This will speed up performance. But make sure you insert valid data only. After inserting re-enable the constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SQL Compact Bulk Insert Library](https://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/) library to insert the data in bulks.

If you need to update any records, then use this technique:

1. Create a staging table in your database
2. Use the library to bulk insert into the staging table
3. Then execute a stored procedure to do an update by reading from the staging table and updating the target table's records.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. What I don't know is - how will I get the IDs of the inserted rows? I need them as references for inserts in the other tables.

Comment: You can pre-assing the key values, and set an option to use INDENTITY_INSERT ON

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to use AddRange or alternative solutions to ensure not getting poor performance result due to DetectChanges method.

See: http://entityframework.net/improve-ef-add-performance

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library support all major provider including **SQL Server Compact**

By default, BulkInsert automatically get the IDs of the inserted rows.

This library allows you to perform all bulk operations you need for your scenarios:

- Bulk SaveChanges
- Bulk Insert
- Bulk Delete
- Bulk Update
- Bulk Merge

Example

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Primary Key
context.BulkMerge(customers, operation => {
   operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. It could solve the problem with Entity Framework, but the solution from CodingYoshi is easier to implement in my case.